# Ubuntu 22.04 SSH smart card authentication, how to make enable-ssh-support flag work?

Tags: ssh, authentication, 22.04, gnupg

I'm trying to setup SSH authentication with smart card reader in a clean Ubuntu 22.04 install. When ssh it doesn't try to authenticate using smart card reader but it just says "*ec2-user@myserver.com: permission denied (publickey).*"

Gpg-agent works for signing and decrypting with SC but it doesn't work for SSH authentication.
I've set *enable-ssh-support* flag in *.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf* but it doesn't work like it used to work in my old Ubuntu 16.04.

Also from *https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/701131/use-ntrux25519-key-exchange-with-gpg-agent* I've tried setting "*KexAlgorithms -sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com*" option in client *~/.ssh/congig*, in server */etc/ssh/sshd_config* and in both with no luck.

Also I tried setting "*PKCS11Provider /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so*" option in *.ssh/config*, but I'm not sure if this option is for other type of card but *gnupg*.

These commands were executed initially:

```
$ sudo apt install gnupg2 gnupg-agent pcscd scdaemon pcsc-tools opensc gpgsm
$ sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop.inactive
$ echo "enable-ssh-support" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
$ gpg2 --import public-armored-stub.gpg
$ gpg2 --edit-key <mykey>
    gpg> trust
    Your decision? 5
    Do you really want to set this key to ultimate trust? (y/N) y
    gpg> quit
```

Appart, if I plug the reader (with same SC) to my old laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 it works perfectly even without installing drivers from Identiv website.
I'm using Identiv card reader (SCM SPR332 V2 - Pinpad Reader) with a gnupg v2.1 SC on Ubuntu 22.04.
Any idea on what is left?

Answer (score 0):

Finally for setting up SSH authentication with smart card in Ubuntu 22.04 just 2 more config files were to be edited compared with older versions. I found info [here](https://mlohr.com/gpg-agent-for-ssh-authentication-update/).

Appart, there was no need to edit Gnome keyring autostart files and also no drivers were needed, at least for Nitrokey Pro and Identiv SCM SPR332 V2 Pinpad Reader. However a Cherry keyboard with SC reader (KC 1000 SC) was not running with this procedure.

I also found that only scdaemon package needed to be installed. All this was tested in another fresh install.

**Setup:**

```
$ sudo apt install scdaemon
$ echo "use-agent" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf
$ echo "enable-ssh-support" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
$ echo "IdentityAgent /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh" >> ~/.ssh/config
```

**Addind public keys stubs to keyring:**

```
$ gpg2 --import public-armored-stub.gpg
$ gpg2 --edit-key <mykey>
    gpg> trust
    Your decision? 5
    Do you really want to set this key to ultimate trust? (y/N) y
    gpg> quit
```

In my case public SSH keys on server were already at ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.